# How to install Yii framework in an android device?

Tags: applications, installation

I am studying Yii framework in my android phone. I have an application called AndroPHP. It has a **LightHttpd, MySql and PHP**.

I can run CodeIgniter, Wordpress and Smarty in my phone but I don't have an idea how can I install a Yii framework. I searched in the Internet I can't find any correct solution.

I tried to install it using the yiic webapp in my android terminal emulator. And my error is

**sh: yiic: not found**

I have a YII framework extracted in **sdcard/www/YII/**

And I used the yiic in the framework folder.

To access the yiic I have this path:

**root@android:/storage/sdcard0/www/YII/framework#**

And to use the yiic I have this

**yiic webapp sdcard0/www/bid**

where **bid** is my folder under **www**

Any idea how can I install this framework? Or any android application that has a tutorial in installing Yii. Ok that's all thanks.

Comment: You can't execute anything from the SD card.  Are you rooted?

Answer (score 0):

PHP mySQL Server app is available for android device.

Install it and then download and generate your Yii project by using cmd, then copy that project to your android device WAMP root directory. For better development, install it on your pc.

Before running the command in the cmd, install php and make sure to set the php path in your system environmental variables.

Comment: What app is "Wamp Server"? I couldn't find anything called that exactly, and a google search returned a paid app called Bit Web Server. Please post a link to the app you suggest.

Comment: the name is not exactly same, free apps are available like Server for PHP, Ulti Server, KSWEB you may try any one of these